# Adding objects with onTouchEvent

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am hoping someone can help with this - I am developing a live wallpaper in Opengl es 2.0. I am ok with everything except for one area. When the user touches the screen, I want a new object to appear at that specific point. But I can't get it to work.

here's my code for the renderer

```
    public class Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer 
{

     private final Context mActivityContext;

     private float x = 0;

     private float y = 0;

     private Object mObject;

    public Renderer(final Context activityContext){ 

    mActivityContext = activityContext;

}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config){


        if (mObject!=null){

            //code below initiates textures and shaders
        mObject.onSurfaceCreated(mActivityContext);

        }

            //view matrix code goes here

}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height)  {

//setup projection matrix
```

}

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {


    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

     if (mObject!=null){

     mObject.drawParticle();

     mObject.update();





                }

}

 public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {

        if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        x = me.getX();
        y = me.getY();

        //add new object 
        mObject = new Object (x,y);


}

}
}
```

When I touch the screen, nothing happens (object isn't added). What am I doing wrong, please?

Many thanks in anticipation.